# What are the requirements for unlocking Epona?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

According to multiple sources online (including video evidence), you can get Epona in *Breath of the Wild* by using the Link Amiibo from *Super Smash Bros.*

Before knowing this, I had already used that Amiibo and it just gave me a few random resources. When I found out about Epona later, I assumed it probably didn't work for me because I did it too early (it was at the very beginning of the game, maybe even before getting to the first tower - the game probably wouldn't want me to have a horse at that point).

However, when I tried it again the next day (having made quite a bit of progress and owning three horses), the same thing happened again. Just random stuff, no Epona.

Are there any specific requirements for this to work, or did I somehow break my save file by using the Link Amiibo too early?

I'm playing the Wii U version if that makes any difference.

Comment: Well, I didn't tried it yet, but some websites say that you need to 'be in the Plains of Epona to have any chance of success. Otherwise, you’ll just get a chest with, admittedly, some cool items, such as Twilight Link’s tunic.'
Can you try that ?
(I'll buy that amiibo instantly if that work !)

Comment: @Ise Is "Plains of Epona" an area in the game? If so, I haven't heard of it yet, and can't seem to find any info about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/How_to_Get_Epona) you should have gotten it on your first use of the amiibo. And if you did not put Epona into a stable you may not get her to summon again. It does not seem that there are any requirements for getting her to summon other than using the amiibo and it being the first time doing so, there are no indicators that using it at a specific point in the game changes how this works.

> If the player has the Smash Bros. Series Link Amiibo, you can use the
>   Amiibo Rune to tap Link onto the NFC reader. While most other Amiibo
>   will summon a supply drop of items - **the first time the Smash. Bros
>   Series Link is used, Epona will be summoned instead.**

So my guess is, based off their explanation, is that you potentially summoned her and didn't notice and it may be stuck where you can't summon her again. Or you summoned her in the Plateau and you did not get to put her in a stable, thus she disappears.

> However, if you wish to keep and ride Epona - you must register the
>   horse at a stable as soon as possible. **If you summon Epona in a place
>   where you cannot get to a Stable, like on the Great Plateau, you will
>   be unable to summon Epona again**, as using the Smash. Bros Series Link
>   Amiibo on other days will only summon standard supply drop items.

However; there is [another article](http://www.gameskinny.com/rs233/breath-of-the-wild-guide-horse-taming-101) that mentions a fountain that may be of help to you.

> The downside, of course, is that if Epona dies -- that's it. You
>   cannot respawn Epona by tapping the amiibo again after she dies, and
>   you will only be able to get her by restarting your game or by finding
>   the [Horse God's Great Fairy Fountain](http://www.gameskinny.com/lfe69/breath-of-the-wild-guide-great-fairy-locations).

So perhaps there is a chance you can get Epona back, based off of what that article says:

> Unlocking this Great Fairy will allow you to bring any horse back to
>   life -- provided that it was registered, and that you have the means
>   to pay for it. Even legendary or rare horses can be brought back to
>   life at this fountain -- including Epona **(provided you already
>   summoned her with an amiibo)**.

But since it doesn't seem like you registered her if she did spawn by chance, it may not work either. The only solution remaining after that, as far as I can tell, is restarting, which I can't imagine you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm fairly certain Epona did not spawn, since in the videos I saw she was the only spawn that happened, while I got some items and a chest. I'll wait to see if I can get any more info, but yeah, restarting would suck.

Comment: Were you in the plateau when you used it?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, there was an item drop, no horse to be seen. I can imagine the game thinking I've already spawned her though, maybe it only remembers that the amiibo was used before and won't give me another chance. I really should have looked up what it's supposed to do before...

Comment: That could be part of the issue, since it may have seen you were in a place where you could not register her which may have bugged it out, and now that it's been used it probably won't show again.

Comment: [Apparently I'm not the only one with this problem.](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/48903/) I'll probably just keep playing for now and hope it's eventually patched.

Comment: Where did you use the amiibo the first time? Was it in a place where a horse is not supposed to be (e.g. a tower)?

Comment: @Andii It seems like you can try again and again to re use the amiibo and you might be lucky enough to get her a second time. People speak about trying 50 times and getting her :) http://press-start.com.au/guides/2017/03/06/can-get-epona-zelda-breath-wild-second-time/

Comment: @Ise Wow, that's great news, thanks! Haven't had any luck so far, but I'll keep trying. :)

Comment: Quick update: I finally managed to unlock Epona. It turned out to be surprisingly easy if done in a certain way. I posted my solution [as an answer to another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302360/what-to-do-if-i-did-not-register-epona-from-the-super-smash-brothers-link-amiibo/302582#302582) (because it fit that one better than mine).

Comment: you will need the right amino to get epona.DO NOT SUMON HER ON THE GREAT PLETU.other wise you will never get her agen.once you have epona,bord her at a stable.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to miss on Epona if you use the Link Amiibo the first time **in a place where horses cannot spawn**. That may happen inside caverns, sanctuaries, ruins, on the volcano, or inside a village or a relay.

If you want to be sure, try a place where you see wild horses.

Note that you can only get Epone on **the very first time** you use the Amiibo in a given game. Trying again the next day, or after quitting and re-entering the game, or after using a different Amiibo, doesn't work.

The good news is that you don't have to restart the game from scratch if you miss Epona, provided that you act right away and load a previous save. Then you'll have another shot.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably not using the right Amiibo.

I got Epona the first time I used the Super Smash Bros. Link Amiibo, that looks like Link with a Hylian shield in this battle pose. There is a chance you get treasure instead, but I think it's a 90% chance to get Epona.

Probably bad luck, or wrong Amiibo