# What to do if I did not register Epona from the Super Smash Brothers Link amiibo at a stable

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, amiibo

Unknown to me before I first used the SSB Link amiibo, **only the first time you use the amiibo** will spawn Epona for you.

So I used my amiibo for the first time and got Epona. Thinking "Well, I don't need her right now. I can get her back later" I fast travelled somewhere else without registering her at a stable.

Now I know that she will never spawn again from that amiibo, so how can I get Epona back? Will she be at the place where I left here? Is she a wild horse now or did she despawn? Can I use a different SSB Link amiibo to get her back?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [What are the requirements for unlocking Epona?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302229/what-are-the-requirements-for-unlocking-epona)
The difference: I got Epona on the first use and I left her **alive, but unregistered** at some place I do not remember exactly. I just want to know if I can still find her there, theoretically.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302229/what-are-the-requirements-for-unlocking-epona

Comment: @Ise I saw that thread, but it does not answer my question. I already got Epona, rode her for a minute and went away.

Comment: Then all is written in it as the person ask how he can get back Epona when having already used the amiibo, such as : 'However, if you wish to keep and ride Epona - you must register the horse at a stable as soon as possible. If you summon Epona in a place where you cannot get to a Stable, like on the Great Plateau, you will be unable to summon Epona again,' and 'Unlocking this Great Fairy will allow you to bring any horse back to life -- provided that it was registered, and that you have the means to pay for it. ' So the answer is really in there and that's almost a duplicate, but maybe ...

Comment: you still have a chance. 'I lost Epona, and I was persistent on getting her back and used my Link amiibo a ton (I swear at least 60 times or so). She's incredibly rare, but she's still possible to get!'
I saw two people speaking about how they could get her back after spamming the amiibo.

Comment: That does not apply to me. I summoned Epona *in a place where I can* get to a stable theoretically. I just don't know where exactly it was and it is several ingame hours in the past. She is still alive (as far as I know), I just left her untamed and unregistered. Edit: Thanks for the second comment, I will try that as soon as I get home.

Comment: @Wouter Ise already linked that thread and I already explained why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Does an unregistered Epona leave a horse icon on your map?

Comment: @CyberSkull I am 99% certain that she does not leave an icon when unregistered, I would have noticed that. I will check in a few hours if she is where I left her.

Comment: I WANT TO CONFIRM METHOD!!! These were my steps:
1. Catching a New horse and register 2. Using my splatoon amiibo 3. Saving and wait untill next day (Link amiibo was already used this day)
4. (Next day) Used splatoon amiibo 5. Used Link amiibo and TA-DA Epona appeared in först try

Comment: I'll just confirm too that when I first scanned the Link amiibo in a game in which I had already defeated two dungeons, she didn't appeared. Then, 2 weeks later, as I was scanning Link for the more than 15th time, she finally decided to show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the one who asked [What are the requirements for unlocking Epona?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302229/what-are-the-requirements-for-unlocking-epona), and I think I may have a solution. I'm posting it here since my question already has a fitting answer, considering how it was worded. Of course my situation wasn't quite the same since Epona did not spawn the first time I used the amiibo, but maybe it'll work for you as well.

As discovered by user SkipReplay in [this thread](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/48903), there seems to be a much higher chance of getting Epona to (re)spawn if you use other amiibos in-between attempts. Just load your save (wait until the next day if you've already tried using the Link amiibo) and go through as many amiibos as you can, then use Link last. Of course you need a couple of other amiibos to do this, but it doesn't seem like the required amount is very high (I scanned 7 other amiibos, fewer than that could be enough as well).

Not sure why this works, but for at least two people (SkipReplay and myself) it worked on the first try.

Comment: Perhaps that explains my experience. I have a kind of ridiculous number of Amiibos to draw on.

Comment: I finally got her back! I was at a stable, used 6 non-Zelda amiibos and then SSB Link gave me Epona again! Registerer her right away :)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get Epona again after she got stuck, and in fact got a second Epona right after. I believe the criteria is that if she exists in the world, she will not appear by using an Amiibo. Try catching and registering a horse, maybe take it out and reboard it before trying again.

---

My experience was summoning her before finding my first stable. I left her next to a river near the Dueling Peaks as I went after a tower. When I returned some monsters spawned and scared her in to the water. She proceeded to swim towards a small island and would not reenter the water when I tried to steer her to the shore.

Midnight passed and I tried the Amiibo again, which gave the chest and materials like other Zelda Amiibos return. I happened to catch and register a horse before trying the Amiibo a third time, as well as traveling great distances. On day three the Super Smash Bros. Link Amiibo gave me Epona once again, who I registered and boarded immediately.

I dug out my own set of Amiibo that same day, as I had been using my wife's before, and my own SSB Link Amiibo gave me another Epona! After registering her I now have two at the stables.

Comment: I guess I will use a friend's Link amiibo then to get her another time. My own amiibo did not give me Epona on my second day.

Comment: @Gwellin Maybe the second time you tryed the amiibo, Epona was still in the world. So for the 3rd time that you used the amiibo, I would think she was not in the world anymore. It most problably be due to de distance or changing of area, but did the red moon event take place during the second day? (the way this event "resets" the world would make sense) Just asking to understand how the game works in this matter.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that the blood moon occurred during that time, but I also caught two other horses, shut down and reopened the game, traveled great distances and cleared the first Devine Beast in that time.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing and didn't register Epona, and had been trying ever since to get her back. So I just bought the DLC and updated the game. The first time I tried the amiibo again Epona appeared. I don't know if its coincidence or not, but it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I made the same mistake other folks did and summoned Epona on the Great Plateau. So I searched for any other way to get her back. After several failed attempts I finally got her back and I wanted to share it for others who may need her.

I did the amiibo exploit of changing the date on my Switch. 
Since I was supposed to catch 2 horses I just went ahead and caught the maximum I could have in the stable (5/6 I think) 
I have only 1 non-Zelda amiibo so I just used it once a day using the exploit.

About 11 days later I saved my game and gave my Action Replay PowerSaves amiibo (loaded with SSB Link) a shot and voila! Epona appeared right there in front of the Highland Stable!