# Can you scan Amiibos more than once?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, amiibo

Are the rewards from scanning Amiibos a one time deal or can you scan more than once? Tried googling it but all that comes up is what rewards the Amiibos give, and not the frequency.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I did find out using additional copies of the same amiibo works, at least when we tested archer Link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said by Ari you can **scan Amiibo's once per day** but as mentioned by Timmy some things are going to be different.

For **wolf link** for example, you can scan him **multiples time a day**, as he will 'go back to his world' after a cutscene, entering a dungeon ... But you will be able to make him spawn again by re scanning the Amiibo.
Except when he dies, you will then have to wait a day.

All the **Zelda's Amiibos** will give you some **rare stuff**, so most of the time you will gain meat/fish/plants depending on which amiibo you use, but sometimes a rare bow/sword will drop too. (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302515/what-amiibos-can-be-used-and-what-are-their-effects) for which amiibos drop what)

And finally there are some you really want to think about it twice before using as what they invoke will pop up **only once** and depending of where you are at the moment will possibly lost forever. But I'm not going to spoil you furthermore if you want to discover what will be invoked depending of which Amiibo and all :)

Comment: Correction: You cannot use Wolf Link again after he dies. If he dies, you can only use the amiibo again the next day. You *can* use him again if he "went back to his world" because you teleported, went into a shrine, entered a cutscene, etc.

Comment: Okay thanks for correcting that as it never happened to me ^^ I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: I learned the hard way encountering a guardian :/

Comment: Haha. That's why you need the guardian amiibo ^^ @ian_itor

Comment: What counts as a "day" in the game? I scanned all my amiibo last weekend and I still cannot rescan them. And I'm pretty sure I exit the game a couple of times since then.

Comment: Hmm, seems like I didn't exit the game after all.  I was able to use them after restarting the game.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Amiibo_Functionality) IGN article:

> Amiibo can be scanned once per day.

This implies you can also get the Amiibo's associated rewards once each day.

Comment: I think some rewards change after the first scan.  See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302515/what-amiibos-can-be-used-and-what-are-their-effects) and its answers for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some interesting notes from my personal experience.

If you have duplicates of any amiibo they are treated as individuals when used the day of. For example I can scan both smash bros link I have for extra stuff.

The BOTW specific amiibo definitely drop chests and good items AS WELL as any other Zelda related amiibo!

Using any other amiibo not related to Zelda is still worth it as they drop bout 6 items or so (random things too).

All the meat you get from amiibos is also great to sell for a quick buck.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vemonous' answer, one cool thing that I noticed is that duplicate amiibos appear to be totally unconcerned with special items. While it's kind of useless having two Eponas, that's totally a thing I have going on now and it's pretty rad.